# How to send event from MainActivity onCreate to React Native?

Tags: java, react-native

I'm working on an alarm clock and I can't figure out how to sendEvent to React Native from MainActivity. This is what I managed to do so far:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mInitialProps = new Bundle();
        final Bundle bundle = mActivity.getIntent().getExtras();      
        ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager = getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager();
        ReactApplicationContext context = (ReactApplicationContext) mReactInstanceManager.getCurrentReactContext();    
        if (context == null) {
            mReactInstanceManager.addReactInstanceEventListener(new ReactInstanceManager.ReactInstanceEventListener() {
                public void onReactContextInitialized(ReactContext context) {
                    if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("sendAlarm")) {
                        if (bundle.getString("sendAlarm").equals("sendAlarmOn")) {
                            LauncherModule.startAlarm(mActivity); // works 
                            LauncherModule.sendAlarmEvent(); // doesn't work. Should run after alarm manager starts app which previously had been killed
                        }
                    }                                
                }
            });
        } else {
            if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("sendAlarm")) {
                if (bundle.getString("sendAlarm").equals("sendAlarmOn")) {
                    LauncherModule.startAlarm(mActivity); // works
                    LauncherModule.sendAlarmEvent(); // works and sends event only when app was left open
                }
            }                  
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

The code works only If app is left open and alarm manager restarts app itself. If I close the app and alarm manager starts it then it seems that only `startAlarm` function (it has sound effect) is beeing triggered..

No matter what I do whether I put sendEvent function inside Mainactivity or elsewhere (e.g. external module) it simply won't send event if I close the app. I also tried `getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext()` combined with `while` from this question [Send data from Android activity to React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48445010/send-data-from-android-activity-to-react-native) to no avail.

Also tried to create bolean beeing set to true onCreate and then send event onStart or onRestart. Also to no avail.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Here is how sendEvent function looks like:

```
public final void sendEvent(String eventName, boolean isAlarmOn) {  
    getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext()
        .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
        .emit(eventName, isAlarmOn);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Well I think that the answer is not to use sendEvent method onCreate because (I might be wrong) listener seems to be initialized after the event had been sent. So nothing is going to listen to this event.

It seems to work pretty well inside onStart, onRestart, onPause though.

What can we do? React Native provides `ReactActivityDelegate` with initial props. And it does the job!

`ReactActivityDelegate` in `MainActivity` should look as below:

```
public class ActivityDelegate extends ReactActivityDelegate {
    private Bundle mInitialProps = null;
    private final @Nullable Activity mActivity; 

    public ActivityDelegate(Activity activity, String mainComponentName) {
        super(activity, mainComponentName);
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mInitialProps = new Bundle();
        final Bundle bundle = mActivity.getIntent().getExtras();  
        if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("sendAlarm")) {
            if (bundle.getString("sendAlarm").equals("sendAlarmOn")) {
                mInitialProps.putBoolean("alarmOn", true);
            }
        }       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bundle getLaunchOptions() {
        return mInitialProps;
    }
};

@Override
protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new ActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName());
}
```

Then in your main app component (usually index.android.js) call your propTypes and use them to run your code:

```
static propTypes = {
    alarmOn: PropTypes.boolean
}

componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.alarmOn === true) {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Voila!

You can find full example here: https://github.com/vasyl91/react-native-android-alarms