# How to dispatch intent to MainActivity from another activity? (react native)

Tags: java, android, react-native

I've created a custom deep link dispatcher in Java within a react native project.

The issue I'm having is that I can't get `MainActivity` to start from my dispatcher, and I can't quite figure out why.

I have AndroidManifest set up so that the deep link is captured in `LinkDispatcherActivity` effectively, but the `startActivity(dispatchedIntent)` never reaches `MainActivity`, which is where I assume it needs to go. Ordinarily in AndroidManifest.xml, deep links would be sent to `MainActivity`).

It does open the app, but I assume it's because `LinkDispatcherActivity` is part of the app? Not sure, if I say something dumb it's because this is only my 3rd day in a row writing Java

Below is my code.

```java
package com.example.app;

//Inspired by https://github.com/justeat/Android.Samples.Deeplinks, Licensed under Apache 2.0

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity;

public class LinkDispatcherActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            dispatchIntent(getIntent());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            // Malformed URL
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Log.e("Deep links", "Invalid URI", iae);
            }
        } finally {
            // Always finish the activity so that it doesn't stay in our history
            finish();
        }
    }
    public void dispatchIntent(Intent intent) {
        final Uri uri = intent.getData();
        final String host = uri.getHost().toLowerCase();
        if (uri == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Uri cannot be null");
        // Default intent
        Intent dispatchedIntent = new Intent(LinkDispatcherActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        dispatchedIntent.setData(uri);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        Log.d(dispatchedIntent.getDataString(), "dispatchIntent: intent string");
        // Auth intent only, this is why I need the dispatcher
        if ("login".equals(host)) {
            dispatchedIntent = new Intent(this, RedirectUriReceiverActivity.class);
            dispatchedIntent.putExtra("requestCode", 0);
            Log.d("Login", "mapAppLink: ");
            startActivityForResult(dispatchedIntent, 0);
            return;
        }
        Log.d("Default", "mapAppLink: ");
        startActivity(dispatchedIntent);
    }
}
```

This is what my AndroidManifest.xml looks like:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  package="com.example.app">

  <!-- < Only if you're using GCM or localNotificationSchedule() > -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <permission
    android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  <!-- < Only if you're using GCM or localNotificationSchedule() > -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

  <application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
    <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="<redacted>" />

    <!--  < Notification Services >  -->
    <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
      android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notification" />

    <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
      tools:replace="android:resource"
      android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />

    <!-- Change the value to true to enable pop-up for in foreground on receiving remote notifications (for prevent duplicating while showing local notifications set this to false) -->
    <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground"
        android:value="true"/>
    <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
      tools:replace="android:value"
      android:value="rn-push-notification-channel-id" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_name" android:value="Default Channel"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_description" android:value="Default channel for push notifications"/>
    <meta-data
      android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color"
      android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />

    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions" />
    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- START: Add this-->
    <service
        android:name=".MainNotificationService">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.intercom.reactnative.RNIntercomPushBroadcastReceiver"
        tools:replace="android:exported"
        android:exported="true"/>

    <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|uiMode"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LinkDispatcherActivity"
    tools:node="replace">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data 
            android:scheme="example"
            android:host="login" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Edit: for the intent, I've tried:
`new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class)`
`new Intent(reactContext, MainActivity.class)` (extending ReactActivity instead of Activity)
`new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)`
`new Intent("MainActivity")`

Comment: try getApplicationContext() other than LinkDispatcherActivity.this

Comment: Thank's Ajay, I tried it that with the same result.

Comment: Could you post your manifest file? Also I think the line "intent.addFlags(" should be "dispatchedIntent.addFlags("

Comment: @N1234 posted the android manifest. I updated the `addFlags` command as you suggested, still no luck getting the data from the original intent nor passing it on. I played around a lot with different intents, different contexts, and different activities, and I'm not sure what the "right" one is... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with for the LinkDispatcherActivity. To summarize, what I did was dispatch the intents that the deep activities were eventually supposed to invoke *directly*, instead of trying to forward the intent. In other words, if you're trying to pass an intent from one activity to another, maybe don't and consider dispatching the activity/function/intent that you want to run afterwards. I still think forwarding the intent *should* have worked, but this is what ended up working.
In order to accomplish the above, I:

- Called a function within the AppAuth package that generates an intent, and dispatch it
- Used ReactContext to emit the `url` listener event that React Native uses to respond to deep links.

Below is the code:

```java
//Inspired by https://github.com/justeat/Android.Samples.Deeplinks, Licensed under Apache 2.0
package com.example.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

import net.openid.appauth.AuthorizationManagementActivity;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;


public class LinkDispatcherActivity extends ReactActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try {
            dispatchIntent(getIntent());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            // Malformed URL
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Log.e("Deep links", "Invalid URI", iae);
            }
        } finally {
            // Always finish the activity so that it doesn't stay in our history
            finish();
        }
    }

    public void dispatchIntent(Intent intent) {
        final Uri uri = intent.getData();
        final String host = uri.getHost().toLowerCase();
        if (uri == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Uri cannot be null");
        // Default intent, e.g. settings, fitbit
        // wait for react context
        ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager = getReactInstanceManager();
        ReactContext reactContext = reactInstanceManager.getCurrentReactContext();
        Intent dispatchedIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        dispatchedIntent.setData(uri);
        dispatchedIntent.putExtra("url", uri.toString());
        dispatchedIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        // Auth intent only
        if ("login".equals(host)) {
            Intent authIntent = AuthorizationManagementActivity.createResponseHandlingIntent(getApplicationContext(), uri);
            startActivity(authIntent);
            return;
        }
        // Below from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48445010/send-data-from-android-activity-to-react-native?rq=1
        WritableMap uriMap = Arguments.createMap();
        uriMap.putString("url", uri.toString());
        if(reactContext != null) {
            reactContext.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                    .emit("url", uriMap);
          // If there's no context, create a listener to wait for it
        } else {
            reactInstanceManager.addReactInstanceEventListener(new ReactInstanceManager.ReactInstanceEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onReactContextInitialized(ReactContext context) {
                    context.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                            .emit("url", uriMap);
                    reactInstanceManager.removeReactInstanceEventListener(this);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding RedirectUriReceiverActivity to the manifest - I couldn't see it in there.

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.RedirectUriReceiverActivity" />
```

Comment: That's how react native is, MainActivity invokes react native and all the rest. It's good to know for general android dev though.

Comment: I don't see the RedirectUriReceiverActivity in the manifest could it be that "dispatchedIntent = new Intent(this, RedirectUriReceiverActivity.class);" is casuing an issue as the activity is not in the manifest?